# Replacing electric tankless water heater

Tags: tankless

I'm replacing my broken seisco 28 using 2 - 60 amp circuits with a ecosmart 18 using 2 - 40 amp circuits.  Looks easy but can I use the existing circuits. 
 I'd hire a professional but I live miles from the closest town. 
Please help 2 retired female teachers get hot water. 
Thank you

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange.  Creating custom step-by-step is not practical.  What you have written leaves the impression that you don't even know where to start, and are attempting to learn electrical for this project.  That's great.  But you need a **well-rounded primer** on the subject, because *many* things can blindside you.  I would go to a library and browse books on home electrical until you find one which feels accessible, then read it cover to cover.  Google is no substitute: Google only answers questions and *you can't know which questions to ask* without a primer.

Comment: Straight back to your question, you can use existing wiring but you'd need to change breakers to 40A, which I'd call "sophomore level" work, $9 per breaker x2.  Be cautioned that you'll have 33% less hot water (or 33% less temperature rise at same flow).  Undersizing a tankless is the #1 reason for disappointment.